# Suggestion regarding Python class best practice

Tags: python, oop

I want to create a utility class that will do some simple calculations. For doing that I want to know the best practices.

- One option is to create the class and pass self as the first variable and later instantiate the class.

```
class Sample:

    def add(self, a, b):
        return a + b

foo = Sample() 
foo.add(1, 1)
```

- Another option is to create the method as a static method

```
class Sample:
    @staticmethod
    def add(a, b):
        return a + b

Sample.add(1, 1)
```

Which one is the best practice?

Comment: If your class has no *state*, then there's no point in using a class at all. It is a code smell to find a class in Python with all static methods. If you want to organize your code, just put normal "free" functions in a module.

Comment: `One option is to create the class and pass self as the first variable and later instantiate the class` -- this is confusing to me.  Are you suggesting to invoke `add` directly e.g. `Sample.add(None, 1, 1)` ?  Yes, this runs.  But no, avoid this!

Comment: OK I think you mean just a standard class method.  So you're essentially asking if these utility methods should be static or member methods?  Looks like @Arachchi already got the right answer.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart interested why you think that is a codesmell.  I've done just that when I wanted pure functions to meet some interface requirements enforced at the class level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For utilities, it is not a good practice to write a class and implement static methods.

Static methods: If a method is written to cater to utilities within a class and it doesn't access properties of a class.  [Visit this example](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/staticmethod#:%7E:text=Static%20methods%20have%20a%20limited,class%2C%20we%20use%20static%20functions.)

Your requirement is to create a python file that contains all the common utilities. In that case, just implement functions in the utility.py.

```
def add(a, b):
        return a + b
```

Then you can easily access it like following.

```
utility.add(1,1)
```